# Query String Value Is Not Working Inside The Javascript

Tags: php, fullcalendar, query-string

Hello stackoverflow community, I am facing a problem where my query string isn't working and it's inside the javascript, I use isset and empty to test out results and it keeps saying failed. Here is the code:

```
events:'load.php?loadfor="$id"',
```

The code is inside a fullcalendar script, I want to load an event for specific person.Full code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.click_hire', function(){

    var to_user_id = $(this).data('touserid');
    $id = $(this).data('touserid');

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        nextDayThreshold: '23:59:00',
        forceRerenderToDisplay: true,
        disableDragging: true,
        header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                right:'title',
                center:''
            },
            events:'load.php?loadfor="$id"',
            selectable:true,
            selectHelper:true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay)
            {
                $("#popup").show();
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "YY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                $.ajax({
                    url:"get.popup.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{start:start, end:end, to_user_id:to_user_id},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#popup').html(data);
                    }
                })
            }


        });

});
```

For the testing i put it on my get.popout.php.

```
if(isset($_GET['loadfor']))
{
    echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
}
else if(empty($_GET['loadfor']))
{
    echo "<h1>Failed</h1>";
}
```

Comment: I think something went wrong when generating this `events:'load.php?loadfor="$id"',` code, you probably should have an actual value rather then `$id`

Comment: @Nigel Ren Just now, i tried to change `events:'load.php?loadfor="$id"',` to `events:'load.php?loadfor=4',` and yet it gives me failed

Comment: I'm assuming you want to use the user ID associated with the thing which has been clicked on? In which case you'd need `events:'load.php?loadfor=' + to_user_id,` I'd expect.

Comment: As for the "Failed" message (which I expect is coming from the get.popup.php rather than the load.php?), you send the request to get.popup.php using POST, but your PHP code is looking for data from a GET...clearly these two things don't match. You also don't have a variable called "loadfor" which you send to get.popup.php - you sent that to load.php, but not to get.popup.php. Instead you sent a field called to_user_id, so in get.popup.php change `$_GET['loadfor']` to `$_POST['to_user_id']` and you should have more luck.

Comment: Learn to double-check your work in detail, understand the difference between the Http GET and POST methods, and also learn to debug (e.g. doing a [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) i.e. `var_dump($_GET);` in your PHP would have shown you that the GET data was empty, and also using your browser's developer tools to watch the ajax requests would have shown you what you were sending in each of the two requests). Once you learn basic debugging, and remember to double-check your code, you can sort out these kinds of small difficulties in a few seconds.

Comment: @ADyson I have an if else on my load.php but i mistakenly put the $id, `events:'load.php?loadfor=' + to_user_id` this really works. Thank you bro